# jQuery mouseover function still firing after $(window).resize

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have try to show/hide dropdown on mouseover for deskotop and click on for small 
 view. and, I have use `$(window).resize` function. and, it does working.

My issue is- Here, does still fire `mouseover` function on small view. if, I have try to use `$('element').off('mouseover');` function. So,it is working fine. but, Here, does not work Our another mouseover function.

So, How can I Stop fire `mouseover` function on small view.

Demo in this [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1d5y42L0/)

```js
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  var screensize = $(window).width();
  if (screensize > 600) {
    $(".drop").on("mouseover", function() {
      $('.dropdown-content').stop().slideDown('fast');

      $(this).bind('mouseleave', function() {
        $('.dropdown-content').stop().slideUp('fast');

      });
    });
  } else {
    $(".drop").on("mouseover", function() {
      $(this).css('background', 'red');
    });

    $(".drop").on("click", function() {
      $('.dropdown-content').stop().slideToggle('fast');
    });
  }
}).resize();
```

```css
.drop {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="drop">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not check the window size in your mouseover callback instead of listening on resize?

Comment: Where's the PHP part?

Comment: @Epodax here, have not available php code. I have try to create jquery function. Thanks.

Comment: Then why is your question tagged with php?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that this can be simplified by just checking the width when your callback is executed from the mouseover event.

```
var dropIsDown = false;
$(".drop").on("mouseover", function() {
   if ($(window).width() > 600) {
      $('.dropdown-content').stop().slideDown('fast');
      dropIsDown = true;
   } else {
      $(this).css('background', 'red');
   }
 });

$(".drop").on("mouseleave", function() {
   if (dropIsDown) { 
      $('.dropdown-content').stop().slideUp('fast');
      dropIsDown = false;
    }
 });
```

Comment: also, I want to add Click function for small screen. please check my code. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, you might need some alterations, but this should get you on the right track.  You'd probably want variables in place for when drop should be clickable and when mouseleave should initiate a slideUp and pull those into separate code blocks.

Comment: @cwg I updated the example here for how you could use a variable and a separate event handler, you can apply the same logic for the click event.

Comment: Thats much better. I'd upvote it twice if I could ;)

Answer (score 0):

you should put your logic into function and call it once in document.ready and in resize function. You also need to remove event binding with off to remove previous bind event.
This will work for you:

```
function mouseOverHandler() {
$(".drop").off().on("mouseover", function () {
    if ($(window).width() > 600) {
        $('.dropdown-content').stop().slideDown('fast');
        $(this).bind('mouseleave', function () {
            $('.dropdown-content').stop().slideUp('fast');
        });
    }
    else {
        $(this).css('background', 'red');
        $(".drop").off().on("click", function () {
            $('.dropdown-content').stop().slideToggle('fast');
        });
    }
});
}
 mouseOverHandler();
 $(window).resize(function () {
 mouseOverHandler();
});
```